# Vue: same component multiple times in the same template, with same props and event handlers

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue component that receives a bunch of props through `v-bind` and has multiple event handlers attached using `v-on`.

```
<SomeComponent
  v-for="object in objects"
  v-bind:prop1="prop1"
  v-bind:prop2="prop2"
  v-bind:prop3="prop3"
  v-bind:key="object.created_at"
  v-on:event-one="eventOne"
  v-on:event-two="eventTwo"
  v-on:event-three="eventThree"
/>
```

All works fine.

The problem is that this component can appear on different parts of the interface depending on some conditionals. **It's the exact same component with the exact same props and event handlers**.

Our current approach is a simple copy and paste of all the above lines, but it seems error prone and verbose, since if tomorrow we need to add another event handler (say `v-on:event-four="eventFour"`), it requires it to be added manually to every instance of `SomeComponent` in the template. The same goes for any prop change and so on.

In React we would probably wrap that component in a function and just invoke it like `{renderSomeComponent()}` as needed.

What would the approach be using Vue?

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to use a method to create JavaScript objects for props and events. (You could get away with computed properties except that one of your bindings depends on the object of the `v-for` loop.)

```
<SomeComponent
  v-for="object in objects"
  v-bind="getProps(object)"
  v-on="getHandlers()"
/>
```

```
computed: {
    getHandlers() {
        return {
            "event-one":   this.eventOne,
            "event-two":   this.eventTwo,
            "event-three": this.eventThree
        };
    }
},
methods: {
    getProps(object) {
        return {
            "prop1": this.prop1,
            "prop2": this.prop2,
            "prop3": this.prop3,
            "key":   object.created_at
        }
    },
    eventOne().  { /* ... */ },
    eventTwo()   { /* ... */ },
    eventThree() { /* ... */ }
},
data() {
    return {
        prop1: /* ... */,
        prop2: /* ... */,
        prop3: /* ... */
    }
}
```